# How to edit and delete user information(MongoDB) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in React and JavaScript so i'm terrible in programming for now.

What I want to do is to edit and delete and item in Mongodb when i press a button. I am using Axios to connect with the network and have no clue what to do now and why error is occurring.

I have made update and delete function but it's not functioning. I will really appreciate any help that i am given. Thanks!!!

I created a router for delete function but have no idea to make one for edit function.

this is the edit function

```
Myprofile.js

class Modify extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };
  }

update() {
 Axios.get('/users', {
      params: {
        id: 1
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    });
}

<Button color="primary" onClick={this.update}>EDIT</Button>
```

this is the delete function

```
class Delete extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        modal: false
      };

    }

    delete() {
      Axios.get('/user/delete/'+ this.props.match.params.id, {
        params: { 
           id: this.state.data.userid,

        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      });
      console.log(this.props.data);
    }


 <Button color="danger" onClick={this.delete}>DELETE</Button>
```

and this is the router.js

```
router.js


router.delete('/user/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        const _id = req.params.id;
        Users.deleteOne({ _id }, (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
            req.session.destroy(() => {
                req.session;
                delete res.locals.user;
            });
            res.status(200).redirect('/');
        });
    })
```

```
this is my data

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d648f5e87cb3a1290079c96"), "wishlist" : [ ], "userid" : "123", "password" : "qSx9s1dqN6KRmobPHCn7nODwq42DnfpN6TUmPu8Rzi9VEfYqMzYrK6wT5ATRtvOn9saLcdNpMWtM7kgyXI8/Edj5lZ5XWqXfM4YYTWl8rHHa1QFg8KStd2rTNy0r/ujXAj1YreVRmVtV3pSj/Ey2Jmvf0cwcgvaapQ82vmbbKOc=", "salt" : "sKzE2Fg+fGODHScoZ/r+f6SUafSz5gfB23c1gQcuoBqEpZ/abuMluB5HaNYKl9hMRrv9Y8LdhfiUxcXR6BJWxg==", "email" : "123@gmail.com", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-27T02:03:10.681Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to update user information when  I press EDIT button and delete user information in MongoDB when i press DELETE.

The result I get from delete function is ""TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// defined route in backend
router.delete('/user/delete/:id')
```

The defined HTTP verb is `delete`, so if you want to access this route, you need to send a HTTP request with that verb.

So your request will look like this:

```
// frontend request
delete() {
  Axios.delete('/user/delete/'+ this.props.match.params.id)
}
```

For update it'll be almost the same, check the verb and [axios' docs](https://github.com/axios/axios) for more details related to that verb.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!! i changed Axios.get to Axios.delete but errors still occuring saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" do i need to change the part .then(function (response) also to somethin else??

Comment: In this case, the problem is with your React props, not related to axios. Try to check the content inside `match` object. If you can put your code on GitHub and share it will be easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: Please, upload the entire React structure... I need to check how you are passing props from router and so on =)

Comment: I really apprciate the help your giving me but i figured it out! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the request method: your router expects `DELETE user/delete/:id` but you are trying use `GET`. Change `Axios.get` to `Axios.delete`

for edit it's common to use `PUT` method

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!!  i changed Axios.get to  Axios.delete but errors still occuring saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" do i need to change the part .then(function (response)   also to somethin else??

Comment: this error indicated you are trying to access `this.props.match` but `this.props` is undefined.  I think Jasper Bernales answer + requesting with the correct HTTP method should fix that

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function on this one to get `this` context

```
    delete = () => {
      Axios.get('/user/delete/'+ this.props.match.params.id, {
        params: { 
           id: this.state.data.userid,

        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      });
      console.log(this.props.data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It really helped:))) I combined some of your code and it works!